# Run time error 9 Subscript out of range when activating sheet

Tags: vba, excel

[image: Here is my Code]

[image: After Debugging]

When I try to activate the draftProcedure sheet as the image shows, I get a run time error(even though there are no spelling mistakes). But it runs with no problems when I use another sheet in the same worksheet. What could be my problem here?

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: pls try `Application.Goto Workbooks(...).Sheets(...).Range("A2")` (replace the `...` with the names). Does the error still pop up?

Answer (score 3):

Simple typo:

`draftProcedures` is the "codename" of the sheet. But the `Sheets()` needs the "sheet name"

Simply change your

```
Sheets("draftProcedures").Activate
```

to:

```
Sheets("ProceduresInDraft").Activate
```

or

```
draftProcedures.Activate
```

;)

Comment: Thanks Dirk. This fixed it!

Answer (score -1):

Fully referencing things will be more beneficial. PLus all the selecting and activating is super sloppy

```
Application.Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = 1
```